# Create a new column/table using a given table

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

The dataset looks something like:

| Month | Day | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 | 40 |
| 2 | 11 | 50 |

The actual dataset contains all the months and days of a year. I want to get average for the each month in a new column/table. Should I try a loop?

Comment: `my_data %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(month_avg = mean(X))`

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution for a new column with `mutate`. Consider Jon Springs answer with `summarize`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(Avg_month = mean(X))
```

Output:

```
  Month   Day     X Avg_month
  <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1     1     2    10        20
2     1     3    20        20
3     1     4    30        20
4     2    10    40        45
5     2    11    50        45
```

data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Month, ~Day,  ~X,
      1L,   2L, 10L,
      1L,   3L, 20L,
      1L,   4L, 30L,
      2L,  10L, 40L,
      2L,  11L, 50L
  )
```

Comment: What if an extra column was added for the year? Going by the above code, group_by will look only at the months irrespective of the year. How to solve that?

Comment: If I understand you correct then just `group_by` `year` also. like: `group_by(year, Month)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with base (@akrun's answer), dplyr (@Jon Spring's comment) or data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(X)

X[, .(avgX = mean(X)), by = Month]
```

- `setDT` converts from data.frame to *both* data.frame and data.table.
- The expression `.(avgX = mean(X))` will create on the fly a variable called `avgX` with the mean of X.
- The `by = Month` part groups by month **before** producing the average.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(X ~ Month, df1, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Month <-c(1,1,1,2,2)
Day <-c(2,3,4,10,11)
X <-c(10,20,30,40,50)

df <- data.frame(Month, Day, X)

result <- df %>% 
group_by(Month)  %>% 
  summarise(Month_avg = mean(X)) %>% 
  data.frame()
```